# Can the combined flair restriction of 200+ rep on at least one site be lifted for a Stack Exchange employee?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, combined-flair, stack-exchange-team

I just went over the [list of Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/152859) and this caught my attention:

> [image]

Different look and feel, too gray... poor Ana deserves more in my opinion. I went and dug up [her combined flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2415655.png) just to see the reason it wasn't used:

> You do not have any linked accounts with 200+ rep

True, and generally I totally agree with this but in case of Stack Exchange employee, reputation should not matter or become a barrier.

Can Stack Exchange employees get a colorful flair, even without 200 reputation on a site?

I'm not asking to artificially boost their reputation, but rather to add a check to the code deciding whether to show the flair or not, to check if the user is a staff member, in which case skip the reputation check.

Comment: The sad thing is that even if she gets a load of rep on MSO it still won't be colourful :-(...

Comment: I seem to remember I noticed the inconsistency in the list yesterday, went to replace Ana's MSO flair with network flair, saw the reason it was how it was, discarded the edit.

Comment: @ben but when she gets 200 here on Meta at least she can have the combined flair. :)

Comment: @michaelb958 I was about to do the same but on second thought decided to give this a try. Who knows it might work.

Comment: @Sha, that freehand circle is creepy. Are you a stalker of some kind? ;)

Comment: That would be *unflair*.

Comment: Sha, is this no-repro, or did you have a different example: https://stackexchange.com/users/2415655/ana?tab=accounts  https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2415655.png ?

Comment: @Rob I asked this almost 7 years ago, Ana got 200 rep since then. But the problem still exists, user without 200 rep on any site won't have global flair, even if that user is a staff member.

Comment: @Sha, OK no specific example. **But** what would you suggest that their Flair would be, how should it be calculated? -- If they had 1 reputation on 175+ sites and only visited 50 should they have a Flair of 175 or 50; or would it be 175*200, etc. - or just add what they seem to have, regardless of the value (where some have more than one rep.). --- Some Devs have a few hundred rep over several sites, them too?

Answer (score 16):

**No**.

Why give someone special treatment when reputation and badges (flair) are the measure of our participation on the sites?

Basically, a dev would have to game the system to make this happen, and AFAIK we play a different (fair) game based on actual achievements that unlocks those tiny-colourful things and its associated numbers.

The diamond is enough to mark a new employee as a special user. The rest is up to her/him.

Comment: I sometimes see users without a diamond do things like adding moderator only tags, and upon checking it they turn out to be Stack Exchange employees who got special privilege. That's not gaming the system.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Sure, but getting rep just for being an employee is. It's also pointless, the diamond grants Ana all rep-tied privileges anyway.

Comment: @Yannis I don't suggest or ask to give her reputation, just show the combined flair even without 200+ account.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh, I see. Just got out of a long meeting, I should stay afk until my brain recuperates.