# /review/* failing on SE sites, but not SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, error-message

As of about 15 minutes ago, attempting to access /review queues (but not /review itself) throws a generic "oops" error on *.stackexchange.com (Meta, ELL, Space, RPG, Code Review, …). SO's review is fine for me; I haven't tested SF or SU or AU.

Comment: i have issues in SO too

Comment: Confirmed for Code Review as well.

Comment: Same on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The problem/error is also on security.SE

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I pushed a bug that didn't manifest locally or on dev - a fix is going out now.

Sorry!

Comment: Gotcha, standing by to confirm fix.

Comment: Also, this is probably a good way to farm meta reps: just push a huge breaking bug and patch it quickly :)

Comment: -1 for not having a sufficiently comprehensive local test environment :-)

Comment: @CodyGray haha, true - I don't roll w/ hundreds of local sites.

Comment: *"Also, this is probably a good way to farm meta reps: just push a huge breaking bug and patch it quickly"* only works when we have inside information in said bugs before hand. after all why do you Diamonds need the rep?

Comment: @Memor-X to have a flair! With less than 200 rep, [even SE employee won't have a global flair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207833/can-the-combined-flair-restriction-of-200-rep-on-at-least-one-site-be-lifted-fo)... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That sounds like a bug. Quick! Make a meta post about it!